# SSH and executing command

Tags: linux, ssh

I am trying to ssh into a server and execute several commands on the host.

I managed to do with the following and it works perfectly

```
ssh -t -X thor 'cd /stmp/username; ls -rtl ; rm ~/tmp.file; tcsh -l'
```

Currently, I am trying to expand the command to change directory to the latest folder listed in /stmp/username/

Firstly, I tested the command that I wanted to use in the terminal and it works. It will go to the latest folder in the directory listing. The command is

```
cd `ls -rtl | cut -d' ' -f9 | tail -1`
```

Now i'm trying to combine the above command into the ssh command. But it does not work.

```
ssh -t -X thor 'cd /stmp/username; cd `ls -rtl |cut -d' ' -f9 | tail -1` ; rm ~/tmp.file; tcsh -l'
```

Is there something wrong with my command?

Comment: You have 2-sets of *single-quotes*, wrap the command in double-quotes, e.g. `ssh -t -X thor "cd ... "` to preserve the included single quotes for your space or escape the space.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin This should be an answer, I think.

Comment: Yes, it was kind of a simple one, but I can do a write up. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin changing to double quotes gives out a new error. Now the command list ls the current directory where i executed the command instead of ls in host thor's directory /stmp/username

Comment: Turn the quotes around and do `ssh '... cut -d" "...'`

Comment: [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls(1)`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: Yes, and it worth bookmarking all the guides there [**Bash Guide**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide), [**Bash FAQ**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ), and [**Bash Pitfalls**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls)  (especially the PItfalls `:)`

Answer (score 2):

When your command works from the command-line, e.g.

```
cd `ls -rtl | cut -d' ' -f9 | tail -1`
```

There are no quoting problems present. However, when you attempt to add that to your `ssh` command, you wrap your `ssh` command in *single-quotes*, but you also have included *single-quotes* within your command to enclose the `' '` (space) with the `cut` command -- causing problems.

The simplest solution is to leave the quoting around your `ssh` command to *single-quotes* and change the quote around the `space` to *double-quotes* within it, e.g.

```
ssh -t -X thor 'cd /stmp/username; cd `ls -rtl |cut -d" " -f9 | tail -1` ; rm ~/tmp.file; tcsh -l'
```

(there are no variable or path-expansion issues as a result)

Make the change and let me know if you have further question.

**note:** you should also avoid *command-substitution* using *backticks* in favor of `$(...)` -- much more readable.

Comment: This solution works. Thanks. You mentioned in the post that i should avoid using backticks, can you show an example using $(..)

Comment: Use `$(ls -rtl |cut -d" " -f9 | tail -1)` instead of `\`ls -rtl |cut -d" " -f9 | tail -1\``

Comment: I am just curious why did the `ssh -t -X thor "cd ... "` does not work?

Comment: @nabilishes It makes backticks act locally.

Comment: Since the outer double quotes do not prevent expansion, command was expanding locally -- wrapping in single-quotes prevents all expansion

Comment: Thanks guys for the fast responses. Really appreciate it!

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin I also tried your suggestion using $(..) on a simple script and it does not work. I guess it only works on BASH and not on tcsh.

Comment: Oh, I apologize, you are using c-shell, uugh... You might as well use DOS... Even in it's `tcsh` incarnation, it is nowhere near POSIX compliant. Sorry for the confusion.